# CouchDB: Trouble querying a view with a key using rewrites

Tags: url-rewriting, couchdb

In CouchDB I have created a view called "zip", the map looks like this;

```
function (doc) {
    if(doc.type == 'zip') {
       emit(doc.zip_code, doc)
    }
}
```

I then added a bunch of docs related to zip codes, a sample doc goes like this;

```
{
   "_id": "zip/48114",
   "_rev": "1-990b2c4f682ed0b6a27e2fa0c066c93d",
   "zip_code": 48114,
   "state": null,
   "county": null,
   "rep_code1": "INTL2",
   "rep_code2": "MI1",
   "type": "zip"
}
```

Now when I query the view directly like so,

```
http://localhost:5984/partslocator/_design/partslocator/_view/zip?key=48114
```

I get the row back that I am expecting;

```
{
    "total_rows": 41683,
    "offset": 20391,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": "zip/48114",
            "key": 48114,
            "value": {
                "_id": "zip/48114",
                "_rev": "1-990b2c4f682ed0b6a27e2fa0c066c93d",
                "zip_code": 48114,
                "state": null,
                "county": null,
                "rep_code1": "INTL2",
                "rep_code2": "MI1",
                "type": "zip"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I have then set up a vhost and am using rewrites, and my rewrite for 'zip' looks like this.

```
{from: "/zip/:zip", to: "_view/zip",  query: {"key": ":zip"}}
```

To me this seems like it should be correct, however when I try to query the view with the rewrite url, it always returns zero rows.

rewrite url:

```
http://partslocatordev.com:5984/zip/48114
```

response:

```
{
    "total_rows": 41683,
    "offset": 41683,
    "rows": []
}
```

Am I missing anything here?

Note: I am using rewrites in the same fashion with other views and they work, but I cannot figure out why this one in particular isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that the rewriter is querying `zip?key=":zip"` rather than `zip?key=:zip`. You can use a `formats` field in your rewriter to name how different arguments should be typed. In this case, try this:

```
{
    from: "/zip/:zip", 
    to: "_view/zip",  
    query: {"key": ":zip"},
    formats: {
        "zip": "int"
    }
}
```

Alternatively, in your map function, emit a string as the ID rather than a number, like this:

```
function (doc) {
    if(doc.type == 'zip') {
       emit(String(doc.zip_code), doc)
    }
}
```

That will handle cases where the zipcode isn't an integer, like in the UK.

Comment: at one point I had guessed that was what was happening but my formats was apparently incorrect. I had used ;

    formats: {
        "key": "int"
    }

Instead of:

    formats: {
        "zip": "int"
    }

Now I feel like an idiot :-O

Thanks for your response, it is now working great.

Comment: This formats thing looks interesting, do you know where it is documented?